# Некорректная отправка сообщения через контакт форму!

Tags: java, javamail

Пытаюсь послать нормальный запрос на мой имейл через контакт форму!

Всё получается но в сообшении, которое я получаю в имейле написанно что сообшение было отправленно от меня же (от моего Gmail) а не тот который указывается в форме и в данном коде. При выводе на консоль обьекта я получаю все данные которые были переданы через клиент.

Почему при просмотре мыла того от кого пришло сообшение, 
пишется что от меня же самого ?

```
  public static boolean sendMessage(ContactFormMessage formMessage){

     String username = formMessage.getNickName();
    System.out.println(username);
     String email = formMessage.getEmail();
    System.out.println(email); // Проблема здесь! 
     String ms = formMessage.getMessage();
    System.out.println(ms);

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(recipientUserName,recipientPassword);
                }
            });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(email));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(recipientUserName));
        message.setSubject("Testing from "+username);
        message.setText(ms);

        Transport.send(message);

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: username тоже вы ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

потому что вы в поле `FROM` сетаете не то значение:

```
String email = formMessage.getEmail();
//...
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(email));
```

надо так:

```
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, email); //получатель
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(recipientUserName); //отправитель
```

Из-за спам и фишингов фильтров, нельзя слать письма от чужого имени.